# read MFRD522 data using raspberry pi and send this data by http(python3)

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, rfid

I'm working on a project and I want to use RFID as a position reference(when raspberry pi and MFRC522 read the data, send it to server and make sure where is the position or adjust position while RFID reader is fixed)

My code is below:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import MFRC522
import signal
import socket
HOST = '192.168.11.48'
PORT = 9009

continue_reading = True

# Capture SIGINT for cleanup when the script is aborted
def end_read(signal,frame):
    global continue_reading
    print("Ctrl+C captured, ending read.")
    continue_reading = False
    GPIO.cleanup()

# Hook the SIGINT
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, end_read)

# Create an object of the class MFRC522
MIFAREReader = MFRC522.MFRC522()

# Welcome message
print("Welcome to the MFRC522 data read example")

# This loop keeps checking for chips. If one is near it will get the UID     and authenticate

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.connect((HOST,PORT))


#print("closing client")            
    while True:
        while continue_reading:

          # Scan for cards    
            (status,TagType) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Request(MIFAREReader.PICC_REQIDL)

        # If a card is found
            if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
                print("Card detected")

           # Get the UID of the card
                (status,uid) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Anticoll()

            # If we have the UID, continue
            if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:

                # Print UID
                print("Card read UID: "+str(uid[0])+","+str(uid[1])+","+str(uid[2])+","+str(uid[3]))

                # This is the default key for authentication
                key = [0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF]

                # Select the scanned tag
                MIFAREReader.MFRC522_SelectTag(uid)


            # Authenticate
                status = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Auth(MIFAREReader.PICC_AUTHENT1A, 8, key, uid)
            data = "str(uid[0])"

                msg = data
                sock.sendall(msg.encode())
                data = sock.recv(128)
                print('date from Echo server is [%s]'%data.decode())

            # Check if authenticated
                if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
                    MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Read(8)
                    MIFAREReader.MFRC522_StopCrypto1()
                else:
                    print("Authentication error")
```

*I am using echo server to make sure that it's working
code for echo server is:*

```
import socketserver

HOST = ''
PORT = 9009


class MyTcpHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        print("[%s]conneted"%self.client_address[0])

        try:
            while True:
                self.data = self.request.recv(1024)
                if self.data.decode() == "/quit":
                    print('ended by user [%s]'%self.client_address[0])
                    return

                print('[%s]'%self.data.decode())
                self.request.sendall(self.data)
        except Exceptions as e:
            print(e)


def runServer():
    print("starting echo server")
    print("if you want to close echo server, click Ctrl+C")

   try:
        server = socketserver.TCPServer((HOST,PORT), MyTcpHandler)
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("--- closing server")

runServer()
```

I ran fist piece of code while the second one was running, but only result I got was -

```
Welcome to the MFRC522 data read example
Card detected
Card read UID:178,29,209,48
size:8.
```

Anyone had idea what I should change to make it work?

thanks